# Is there a way to play WAV files in a cooperative way on Linux in Java?

Tags: java, audio, wav, playback

So far I only found two ways:

1. throw exception
2. play nothing

ad.2. Pretty recent code (2010)

- http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84314/wired-for-sound/

but does nothing, not sound at all.

ad.1. For example:

- [Trouble playing wav in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577724/trouble-playing-wav-in-java/577926#577926)
- http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2433454/210342

All I get is exception "Audio Device Unavailable". As this article (2008) -- [lsof |grep snd — how to free a linux sound device](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/lsof-grep-snd-how-to-free-a-linux-sound-device-p25/) -- explains Java has to get exclusive access to audio device.

However I cannot afford such condition. I use sound to notify myself on long running process (several hours), I cannot get rid of all sounds (including those forced via Flash ads) just to make Java comfy.

So for now I use total extreme -- I simply launch external program: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370223/210342 . This is ugly as hell because well new program is launched just to make notification.

### Question

Is there currently a way to play a WAV file:

- on Linux,
- in cooperative way (during Java playback there may be other audio played as well),
- which makes sound,
- in Java (no launching external programs)?

> Java 1.6, openSUSE 11.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to AT answer I drifted from JMF to JMF problems, and that led me to VLC-J. And this is the answer -- in order to use multimedia in Java program simply don't use Java (pity, btw. that Java in year 2012 does not have reliable multimedia layer, gee.).

Marking as solved, because VLC-J allowed me to play audio without problem.

Main project site:
http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/

Minimal playback program:
http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/source/browse/trunk/vlcj/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/minimalmp3/Mp3Test.java

Comment: curious... what jdk were you testing with?  openjdk vs sun might be an issue

Comment: @hricosrealm, at the time of writing OP I was using Sun JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Java Media Framework (JMF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)?

> The Java Media Framework API (JMF) enables audio, video and other
>   time-based media to be added to applications and applets built on Java
>   technology. This optional package, which can capture, playback,
>   stream, and transcode multiple media formats, extends the Java 2
>   Platform, Standard Edition (J2SE) for multimedia developers by
>   providing a powerful toolkit to develop scalable, cross-platform
>   technology.

Comment: Thank you. Actually it does not work for me ;-) but it does not work for a lot of people, even for the plain wav files. Thanks to other posts with problems related to JMF I found other suggestions -- like trying VLC-J.

Answer (score 0):

This site provides a simple swing application to capture and play wav files
http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.sound/capturing-audio-with-java-sound-api.html
You can modify and use the code from the below site 
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml

Cant you simply create a new thread whenever the play action is needed. So that the playing continues irrespective of the background processes

Comment: Please, pay a little attention -- I gave the second link already, it is repeating the same method I already mentioned it is **not** working. The sound is blocked not by Java, but by the system, adding new threads won't change the fact the audio is blocked (at least Java sees it that way).

Answer (score -1):

Java has this support built in (available in javax.sound, javax.sound.sampled packages) on 1.4+ version. It works colaboratively with other applications on the system as it uses platform mixer (ALSA or PULSE)

Comment: The more you repeat the "answer" it does not become more right. Please read the question next time, thank you in advance.

Comment: @macias: In this case, have you checked if the permissions on /dev/(audio|mixer) allow you to open the device? Can you write to PULSE sockets? What distribution are you using?

Comment: If I couldn't, I wouldn't get any sound, would I? Again, check the question, I gave information about Java and system. However, in a second I will close this question as answered, because yesterday's AT's answer gave me the right idea.

Comment: @macias: indeed vlcj is a solution but it adds an extra layer of indirection java will depend on libvlc that will depend on OSS|ALSA|Pulse.
Please check this thread for a different (not necessarily better) solution: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=248326

Comment: of course I would gladly focus on Java-only solution, but sadly, I didn't find any, and don't have time to test and test, this and that, and something else. I spent with Java-only approach too many time, and vlc-j took me what, downloading the jar, and pasting the code. Job done.